# How to restrict user for checking null for singelton instance in C#, .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I don't want that end programmer can user == or != operator against my singelton class.

End user can't do

if( SingleInstace == null)

I have overloaded != and == operator but it doesn't help.

I have a scenario in which I want to dispose of the singleton instance and initialize it with different parameter. For example my singelton instance is DBAccess and I want to intialize it with different server name. Therefore in between the calls of disposing of the singleton instance and intialize it with different server name ; there may be call of null check. In that case my singelton instance will be initialize with old server name.

Please help!!

Comment: Whatever you do, they'll still be able to call object.ReferenceEquals(x.SingleInstance, null). What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: How did you overload `!=` and `==` operators? Did you make them private or throw Exception?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you probably don't want the Singleton pattern (http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/), if you implement it correctly, the Instance will never be null, so why try to prevent someone from comparing with null, it doesn't harm the integrity of your class in any way.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses; I have updated my query to explain my scenrio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is pointless to prevent this.  The client code can always cast it to object.

Answer (score 4):

SingleInstance should be private inside the Singleton class, so that nobody can access it outside of the class's "GetInstance" method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure SingleInstance is the public property that you normally use in place of a getter method in C#, not the backing field. Also the client programmer will still be able to compare the return value from the property/method to null, which is what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

To implement your singleton, you'll use something like this:

```
class HasSingleton
{
    static public HasSingleton Instance {
        get 
        {
            if (_instance==null)
            {
                _instance=new HasSingleton();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    static private _instance;
}
```

That way, you will never be able to get null for

```
HasSingleton.Instance
```

I omitted locking code for brevity.